# that's just me though

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have read the following expression a lot on social media websites?

> that's just me though

sometimes with comma:

> just me, though

What does this expression mean?

Examples:

> That's just me though... [link](https://twitter.com/smc90/status/690667687781863425) (Reply on another tweet )

> ... that's just me though. I'm never satisfied [link](https://twitter.com/tanamongeau/status/679883824587653120)

> I guess I can't. It's not just me though. [Just a Wish Away](https://books.google.ae/books?id=blm8gicS7XwC)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [this](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/but+that's+just+me) . And it should be *reply* not *replay*.

Answer (score 1):

You also see variants of something like this:

> **Is it just me** or does ice cream taste way better than pizza?

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/that's_just_me) says:

> *Interjection* **that's just me**
>   (colloquial, idiomatic) Indicates the expression of a personal opinion, but often used ironically as an understatement.

When you say

> Ice cream is awesome, but pizza is not. Maybe that's just me.

you mean to only convey that it's your personal opinion. But why would you need to make clear that it's only your opinion? It's implied that you're not fully sure of the opinion, otherwise, why claim it's probably only yours?